# Is it possible to show touch feedback on android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am recording screen from the emulator and I would like the video to show where I clicked. How can I able the touch feedback from the emulator?

Answer (score 7):

You enable it in the same place as a real device.

First Enable developer option in emulated device

Settings -> About Emulated Device -> Build Number -> Click multiple times to enable "Developer Options"

then depending on Android version

Settings -> Developer options -> Show taps

Or

Settings -> System -> Developer options -> Show taps